# Angular 4/5 How to implement Http request queuing based on priorities

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tried below in interceptor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HttpRequestsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    requestQueue = [];
    reqCount: number = 0;
    reqFlag: boolean = false;
    prevCount: number = 0;
    obsIntrReq: any;

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
        Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.prevCount++;
        if (this.prevCount >= 4) {
            this.requestQueue.push(req);
            this.obsIntrReq = Observable.interval(1000).do(() => {
                if (this.reqFlag) {                    
                    this.requestQueue.splice(0, 1);
                    return next.handle(this.requestQueue[0]);
                }
            })
                .switchMap(() => this.intervalPreviewChecking(this.reqCount, this.requestQueue.length))
                .subscribe(() => { });
        } else {
            return next.handle(req).pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                    this.prevCount--;
                })
            );
        }

    }

    intervalPreviewChecking(rCount, requestQueueLength) {
        if (requestQueueLength == 0) {
            this.prevCount = 0;
            this.reqFlag = false;
            this.obsIntrReq.unsubscribe();
            return this.obsIntrReq = null;
        }
        if (this.prevCount < 4) {
            this.reqFlag = true;
            return Observable.of(true);
        }
        this.reqFlag = false;
        return Observable.of(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interceptor is called on every HTTP call.

If I had to prioritize my calls, I would not do it in the interceptor, but in my feature.

And that's how I would do it (order = priority of the request).

```
const calls: {order: number, call: any}[] = [];

calls.push({order: 0, call: this.myService.makeCall(0) });
calls.push({order: 1, call: this.myService.makeCall(1) });
// etc. 

const orderedCalls = calls.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order).map(call => call.call);

Observable.forkJoin(orderedCalls);
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for the reply..
Actually i want to queue my requests and send only 4 at a time and remaining should be there in queue. Once one of the request from 4 is finished next one from queue based on priority should be sent

Comment: So basically, you deny to the user what he asked 3 times, then you comply to his request ? Why ?

Comment: In my case i have functionality called as preview which converts HTML into pdf and user can raise multiple requests.
But when more requests are raised by user, my login ping request falls last in queue which leads to user logout.